# Reading audio duration in nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to calculate the duration / length of an audio file. The audio file is first uploaded to S3 and then read in lambda. I am using a library, but it's not really helpful. Please keep in mind all solutions I found were for frontend calculations and not for the backend. I am trying to store the file in the temp lambda folder to read it using the mp3 duration.  get two results when I use the direct S3 url the result is 0:00 and when i use s3.getobject the file cannot be found.

```js
s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: `audio/filename` }, function(err, data){   
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.code, "-", err.message);
                }
                fs.writeFile(`/tmp/filename`, data.Body, function(err){
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err.code, "-", err.message);           
                    }); 
            });
            mp3Duration(`/tmp/filename`, function (err, duration) {
                if (err) return console.log(err.message);
                console.log('Your file is ' + duration + ' seconds long');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to read the file before it's written to the temp directory.

```
s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: `audio/filename` }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { console.error(err.code, "-", err.message); return; }
    fs.writeFile(`/tmp/filename`, data.Body, function (err) {
        if (err) { console.error(err.code, "-", err.message); return;}

        mp3Duration(`/tmp/filename`, function (err, duration) {
            if (err) { console.error(err.message); return;}
            console.log('Your file is ' + duration + ' seconds long');
        });
    });
});
```

Note the `mp3Duration` function is moved into the callback of `writeFile`

I used the following mp3Duration function to test this and it works fine on Node v15.12.0

```
const mp3Duration = (fileName, callback) => {
  // do your work to find the duration and finally call the callback
  callback(null, duration)
};
```

The async/await version with promises would look like this

```
const mp3Duration = (fileName) => {
  // do your work to find the duration and return a promise. In case of error return Promise.reject();
  return Promise.resolve(duration);
};

try {
    const object = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: `audio/filename` }).promise();
    await fs.promises.writeFile(`/tmp/filename`, object.Body);
    const duration = await mp3Duration(`/tmp/app.js`);
    console.log('Your file is ' + duration + ' seconds long');
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the case above it returned neither an error nor the log. My guess is I need to set up a stream to read the audio files. It returned the logs of the function above and below (not included) but I am curious why not inside the mp3 duration.

Comment: @NoahKanyo I have updated the code in the answer